# SoundPool error when playing sound

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

Eclipse (using LibGdx) show this error message every time when a sound (MP3) is played. is it normal?

[image: screen capture]

Comment: im not entirely sure this is an error message may just be some log cat stuffs.... i would research it

Comment: happened with me couple of times. Works fine on desktop but errors on android or vice-versa. For me changing of the Gdx.jar with some another built works and solves the issuse. Give it a try